# Non irreducible characters with real values

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory

**Context.** For an irreducible representation $V$ of a finite group $G$ with character $\chi$, the following classification is well-known (the three cases below being mutually exclusive):

(1) $\chi$ is not real valued (that is $\chi(G)\not\subset \mathbb{R})$ $\iff c(\chi)=0\iff$ there is no nondegenerate $G$-invariant bilinear form on $V$

$(2)$ $V$ is equivalent to a real representation $\iff c(\chi)=1\iff$ there is a nondegenerate symmetric bilinear $G$-invariant form on $V$

$(3)$ $V$ is equivalent to a quaternionic representation $\iff c(\chi)=-1\iff$ there is a nondegenerate skew symmetric bilinear $G$-invariant form on $V$

Here, $c(\chi)$ is the Frobenius-Schur indicator.

In particular, $V$ has real valued character if and only if $c(\chi)\neq 0$ and $(2)$ and $(3)$ gives a complete classification of irreducible representations with real valued characters.

I am now interested in classifying the representations with real valued characters. It is easy to show that $V$ has a real valued character if and only if $V$ is the sum of irreducible representations with real valued characters (which are already classified) and representations of the forms $W\oplus W^*$ where $W$ is irreducible whose character $\chi'$ is not real valued (that is $\chi'(G)\not\subset \mathbb{R}$)

**Question 1.** Is there a characterization of such representations  $W\oplus W^* $ in terms of character values?

Clearly, if a representation $V$ is equivalent to $W\oplus W^* $ , where $W$ is irreducible with non real valued character, then $V\simeq V^*$, the character $\chi$ of $V$ satisfies $\langle \chi,\chi\rangle=2$ and $c(\chi)=0$, if I am not mistaken.

However, these conditions are not sufficient, since they are also satisfied by the sum of a real irreducible representation and a quaternionic irreducible representation.

**Question 2.** Assuming that $\langle \chi,\chi\rangle=2$,  is is true that $V$ is equivalent to $W\oplus W^* $ , where $W$ is irreducible with non real valued character if and only if there exists a nondegenerate hyperbolic $G$-invariant bilinear form on $V$ ?

Comment: Please ask one question at a time